# Is there a way to capture console.log call arguments before or after they happen?

Tags: javascript, typescript, console, console.log

I want to trigger some actions after `console.log` calls but I do not want to override `console.log` it self because I do not want to lose the log position.

I am looking into how to make this and Proxys looked good but using them and tried :

```
var consoleLogProxyHandler = {
    apply: function (target, thisArg, argumentsList) {
        return target.apply(void 0, argumentsList);
    }
};
var consoleLogProxy = new Proxy(console.log, consoleLogProxyHandler);
console.warn("this is line 7");
consoleLogProxy("this is line 3 :(");
```

but I still lose the console position.

[image]

If I proxy just the console and listen to log calls and then return the `console['callKey']` I do not lose the position BUT I do not get the arguments (that is the text given to the console).

So now I am thinking if there is a way to trigger some event or similar after console.log was done but I do not find anything related.

Does an option similar exist?

Edit: Wanted functionality:

```
1.  onConsoleLog(message) {
2.   // I have here the args
3.     maybeAServerLog('the user logged ' + message)
4.  }
5. 
6.  // some magic here...
7. 
8.  console.log('hello');
9.  hello                  - script.js line 8
10. the user logged hello  - script.js line 3
```

Comment: what do you mean by losing the log position? so far I think overriding the console.log with the one you need is a solution.

Comment: Why can't you create a wrapper function for console.log and implement this. Also it would be helpful if you could share your expected output

Comment: @ducmai the file name and line would always indicate the position where `console` is overriden instead of the place the alias was called.. i feel this too :/ for example look at a console.log in a SO snippet in dev tools, you'll see what he means

Comment: No, this is indeed impossible.

Comment: @VijaySingh I have added an expected output and the problem with wrapping/proxing console.

Comment: @Bergi looks like it I am struggling several days with this.

Comment: The only kind of "workaround" we use is keeping the habit to prefix logs with origin, something like `alias.log('fileA funcB - ...')`, but, well, crappy.. It works with a direct alias (no possibility for extra actions) like this though: `aliasLog =  window.console.log.bind(window.console);`

Comment: I have something like that @Kaddath but it gets messy when you need to take more actions like log to a server and or a file or similar. That why I wanted to get the `arguments` or message send to `console.log`.

Comment: @distante If you want to send the log messages to a server, why care about calling the original log function at all?

Comment: @Bergi I mean as side effect. `console.log() locally` and the same to server. But for that the `arguments` are needed.